# Close all infowindows in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am busy with a script that will make a google maps canvas on my website, with multiple markers. I want that when you click on a marker, a infowindow opens. I have done that, and the code is at the moment:

```
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    function addMarker(map, address, title) {
     geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: results[0].geometry.location,
              map: map,
              title:title
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            infowindow.setContent('<strong>'+title + '</strong><br />' + address);
             infowindow.open(map, marker);

          });
        } else {
          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
     });
    }
    addMarker(map, 'Address', 'Title');
 addMarker(map, 'Address', 'Title');
```

This works 100%. But now i want that when one infowindow is open, and you want to open the second, the first one automaticly closes. But i haven't found a way to do that. infowindow.close(); won't help. Has someone an example or a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

infowindow is local variable and window is not available at time of close()

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var infowindow = null;

...

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    if (infowindow) {
        infowindow.close();
    }
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    ...
});
...
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I changed my code from having multiple InfoWindows to having just one that gets closed/opened on each marker.click. Works like a charm.

Comment: @William, any chance you could post a snippet of code for what you did and share it here?

Comment: working perfectly :-) I am using SnazzyInfoWindow.js for info windows and tried this solution. thank you.

Comment: Infowindow has a `setContent()` method. If you don't need multiple Infowindows open at the same time, use only one instance and set its content dynamically. This code is bad in terms of performance.

Answer (score 16):

Declare global variables:

```
var mapOptions;
var map;
var infowindow;
var marker;
var contentString;
var image;
```

In `intialize` use the map's `addEvent` method:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    if (infowindow) {
        infowindow.close();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

For loops that creates `infowindows` dynamically, declare a **global variable**

`var openwindow;`

and then in the `addListener`function call (which is within the loop):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker<?php echo $id; ?>, 'click', function() {
if(openwindow){
    eval(openwindow).close();
}
openwindow="myInfoWindow<?php echo $id; ?>";
myInfoWindow<?php echo $id; ?>.open(map, marker<?php echo $id; ?>);
});
```

Comment: May you explain the purpose of using eval here?

Comment: `openwindow` is a string if we do not use eval the statement will execute as `openwindow.close()` instead of `myInfoWindow1.close()`. Check the error messages you see here: https://jsfiddle.net/ts3z6nw6/1/

Comment: My infowindows are being added via JS - I used the same approach, declaring openwindow outside of my forEach() that creates the markers with windows. In my code I don't need to use eval as openwindow is already the openwindow object.

Comment: you tested in firefox? I was getting the error in Firefox.

Comment: I had success with this approach except I initialized openWindow as an infowindow so no eval necessary

Comment: On firefox, eval is required. It will throw error "TypeError: openwindow.close is not a function" if not since string.

Answer (score 2):

Write this below line after script tag start.

```
previous_Window=null;
```

It will work 100%.  by using this code

```
 radius= circle.getRadius()/1000;
 radius_mile= circle.getRadius()/1609.344;

 newRadious = 'This Circle Radius Covers Approx ' + radius.toFixed(1) + ' Km'+' <br> This circle Radius Covers Approx '+ radius_mile.toFixed(1)+ 'Miles';
            var infoWindow= new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: newRadious
              });
 infoWindow.setContent(newRadious)
 infoWindow.setPosition(circle.getCenter());
 if (previous_Window) 
  previous_Window.close();

  infoWindow.open(map);
  previous_Window=infoWindow;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a sample of my code that maybe can help. I had set only one infowindow object at global scope. Then use setContent() to set the content before show it.

```
  let map;
  let infowindow;
  let dataArr = [
    {
      pos:{lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      content: 'First marker'
    },
    {
      pos:{lat: -34.340, lng: 150.415},
      content: 'Second marker'
    }
  ];

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
    // Set infowindow object to global varible
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    loadMarker();
  }

  function loadMarker(){
    dataArr.forEach((obj, i)=>{
      let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: obj.pos,
        map: map
      });
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.close()
        infowindow.setContent(`<div> ${obj.content} </div>`)
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a dynamic loop that was creating the `infowindows` and markers based on how many were input into the CMS, so I didn't want to create a new `InfoWindow()` on every event click and bog it down with requests, if that ever arose.  Instead, I tried to know what the specific `infowindow` variable for each instance was going to be out of the set amount of locations I had, and then prompt Maps to close all of them before it opened the correct one.

My array of locations was called locations, so the PHP I set up ***before*** the actual maps initilization to get my `infowindow` variable names was:

```
for($k = 0; $k < count($locations); $k++) {
        $infowindows[] = 'infowindow' . $k; 
}
```

Then after initialzing the map and so forth, in the script I had a PHP `foreach` loop creating the dynamic info windows using a counter:

```
//...javascript map initilization
<?php 
$i=0;
foreach($locations as $location) {

    ..//get latitudes, longitude, image, etc...

echo 'var mapMarker' . $i . ' = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng' . $i . ',
          map: map,
          icon: image
      });';

echo 'var contentString' . $i . ' = "<h1>' . $title[$i] . '</h1><h2>' . $address[$i] . '</h2>' . $content[$i] .         '";'; 
echo 'infowindow' . $i . ' = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ ';
echo '    content: contentString' . $i . '
          });';

echo 'google.maps.event.addListener(mapMarker' . $i . ', "click", function() { ';   
    foreach($infowindows as $window) {  
        echo $window . '.close();'; 
    }
        echo 'infowindow' . $i . '.open(map,mapMarker'. $i . ');
      });';

$i++; 
}
?>
...//continue with Maps script...
```

So, the point is, before I called the entire map script, I had an array with the names I knew were going to be outputted when an `InfoWindow()` was created, like `infowindow0, infowindow1, infowindow2, etc...`

Then, on the `click` event for each marker, the `foreach` loop goes through and says close all of them before you follow through with the next step of opening them.  It turns out looking like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mapMarker0, "click", function() {
    infowindow0.close();
    infowindow1.close();
    infowindow2.close();
    infowindow0.open(map,mapMarker0);
}
```

Just a different way of doing things I suppose... but I hope it helps someone.

Comment: that's horrible code to maintain imo.. why don't you print a json array with php and feed that to some javascript code

Answer (score 0):

I have something like the following

```
function initMap()
{
    //...create new map here
    var infowindow;
    $('.business').each(function(el){
        //...get lat/lng
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var content = "contents go here";
        var title = "titleText";
        var openWindowFn;
        var closure = function(content, position){.
            openWindowFn = function()
            {
                if (infowindow)
                {
                    infowindow.close();
                }
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    position:position,
                    content:content
                });
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        }(content, position);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:position,
            map:map,
            title:title.
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', openWindowFn);
    }
}
```

In my understanding, using a closure like that allows the capturing of variables and their values at the time of function declaration, rather than relying on global variables. So when `openWindowFn` is called later, on the first marker for example, the `content` and `position` variable have the values they did during the first iteration in the `each()` function.

I'm not really sure how `openWindowFn` has `infowindow` in its scope. I'm also not sure I'm doing things right, but it works, even with multiple maps on one page (each map gets one open infowindow).

If anyone has any insights, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with marker clusters this one worked for me.

```
var infowindow = null;

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {

        if (infowindow) {
            infowindow.close();
        }
        var markerMap = this.getMap();
        infowindow = this.info;
        this.info.open(markerMap, this);


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple markers you can use this simple solution to close a previously opened marker when clicking a new marker:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                maxWidth: (window.innerWidth - 160),
                content: content
            });

            marker.infowindow = infowindow;
            var openInfoWindow = '';

            marker.addListener('click', function (map, marker) {
                if (openInfoWindow) {
                    openInfoWindow.close();
                }
                openInfoWindow = this.infowindow;
                this.infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

I encourage you to try [goMap](http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/index.php) jQuery plugin when working with Google Maps. For this kind of situation you can set hideByClick to true when creating markers:

```
$(function() { 
    $("#map").goMap({ 
        markers: [{  
            latitude: 56.948813, 
            longitude: 24.704004, 
            html: { 
                content: 'Click to marker', 
                popup:true 
            } 
        },{  
            latitude: 54.948813, 
            longitude: 21.704004, 
            html: 'Hello!' 
        }], 
        hideByClick: true 
    }); 
});
```

This is just one example, it has many features to offer like grouping markers and manipulating info windows.

Answer (score -1):

You should have to click your map - `$('#map-selector').click();`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score -2):

I have been an hour with headache trying to close the infoWindow!
My final (and working) option has been closing the infoWindow with a SetTimeout (a few seconds)
It's not the best way... but it works easely

```
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(html);
    infowindow.open(map, this);

    setTimeout(function(){
        infowindow.close();
    },5000);

});
```