# Close all info windows google maps API V3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do i get all info windows to close upon clikcing another pin or clicking the map in itself? 
I'm using http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html
and a kml overlay.
heres my JS so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    function initialize() {
        google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.201465, -0.30244);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);

        var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: 'http://***.com/new/wp-content/themes/required-starter/CGAGolfAcademies.kml?rand=' + (new Date()).valueOf(),
            suppressInfoWindows: true,
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function (kmlEvent) {
            showInContentWindow(kmlEvent.latLng, kmlEvent.featureData.description);
        });

        function showInContentWindow(position, text) {
            var content = "<div class='info_win'><p>" + text + "</p></div>";
            var infowindow =new InfoBox({
                 content: content,
                 disableAutoPan: false,
                 maxWidth: 0,
                 position: position,
                 pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0),
                 zIndex: null,
                 boxStyle: { 
                  background: "#FBFBFB"
                  ,opacity: 0.90
                  ,width: "280px"
                 },
                 closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px",
                 closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
                 infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
                 isHidden: false,
                 pane: "floatPane",
                 enableEventPropagation: false
        });


    infowindow.open(map);

        }
                    /******AJAX MAP ****/
            siteURL = 'http://' + top.location.host.toString();
            coachesLinks = jQuery('.info_win a');
            coachesLinks.click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            coachesLinks.click(function (e) {
                alert('FRED');
                $el = jQuery(this);
                URL = $el.attr('href');
                shareurl = $el.attr('href');
                URL = URL + " .main";
                jQuery('#content_two').show('slow').load(URL, function () {
                    scrollToAnchor('content_two');
                    $('.main').css('overflow', 'visible');
                    $('#content_two').css('overflow', 'visible');
                    jQuery('#content_two .back').on('click', function () {
                        jQuery(this).hide('slow');
                        var contentTwo = jQuery('#content_two');
                        if (contentTwo.is(':hidden')) {
                            jQuery('#content_two .back').hide();
                        } else {
                            contentTwo.hide('slow');
                            jQuery('#content > .main').show('slow');
                            jQuery('#content > .main').css('overflow', 'visible');
                            scrollToAnchor('access');
                        }
                    });

                });
                $('#content > .main').hide('slow');
            });

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close all infowindows in Google Maps API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539905/close-all-infowindows-in-google-maps-api-v3)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As you see in the [API docs](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html), an InfoBox has a `close()`-method.

Collect all the InfoBox'es you create in an array. Then iterate over this array and call `close` for each infobox, when you need to close them all at once.

In the top, add an array to hold all the infoboxes created

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var infoWindows = [];
```

In function `showInContentWindow` add the following right after `var infowindow=new..`, eg just before `infowindow.open`

```
//add infowindow to array
infoWindows.push(infowindow);
```

add this function

```
function closeAllInfoWindows() {
  for (var i=0;i<infoWindows.length;i++) {
     infoWindows[i].close();
  }
}
```

here called by a link

```
<a href="#" onclick="closeAllInfoWindows();">Close all infowindows</a>
```

Comment: But what about info windows user May have opened bye clicKing google places?

Comment: Great solution. Thanks!

Comment: @FernandoFabreti for Google Places infoWindows, solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61310243/4378314

Answer (score 13):

You can also keep your active (opened) info window in a higher scope or global variable

```
var activeInfoWindow;
```

and in the click event listener, close the active info window (if there's one), then set `this` info window as active

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: name
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  activeInfoWindow&&activeInfoWindow.close();
  infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  activeInfoWindow = infoWindow;
});
```

Comment: This is the best solution if you only have 1x infowindow open at a time

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wants to do this in the context of gmaps3 jQuery wrapper...

```
var infoWindows = [];
var locations=[
    {position:[123,456],content:'<h3>marker title 1</h3><p>msg text</p>/div>'}
]
var map=$('#mapName').gmap3()
.marker(locations)
.infowindow(locations)
.then(function (infowindow) {
    var map = this.get(0);
    var marker = this.get(1);
    marker.forEach(function(item,i){
        item.addListener('click', function() {
            closeAllInfoWindows();
            infowindow[i].open(map, item);
            infoWindows.push(infowindow[i]);
        });
    })
})
.fit();

function closeAllInfoWindows() {
  for (var i=0;i<infoWindows.length;i++) {
     infoWindows[i].close();
  }
}
```