# showing one info window at a time

Tags: knockout.js

I have this project showing multiple locations using Google and Foursquare API. I was able to show the location and create a marker. My question is how do I show one info window at a time? If I click new location, the other location info window doesn't close. Right now if I click on one place and another. Both info window remains open.

My code is as follow. Thank you.

```
var initialLocations = [{
            name: 'Golden Gate',
            lat: 37.819929,
            long: -122.478255
        }, {
            name: 'AT&T Park',
            lat: 37.7749,
            long: -122.4194

        }, {
            name: 'Twin Peaks',
            lat: 37.7544,
            long: -122.4477
        },
    ];

var clientID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

var Location = function(data) {
    var self = this;

    this.name = data.name;
    this.lat = data.lat;
    this.long = data.long;
    this.URL = "";
    this.street = "";
    this.city = "";
    this.phone = "";

    this.visible = ko.observable(true);

    var foursquareURL = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=' + this.lat + ',' + this.long + '&client_id=' + clientID + '&client_secret=' + clientSecret + '&v=20160118' + '&query=' + this.name;

    $.getJSON(foursquareURL).done(function(data) {
        var results = data.response.venues[0];
        self.URL = results.url || 'No url found';
        self.street = results.location.formattedAddress[0];
        self.city = results.location.formattedAddress[1];
        self.phone = results.contact.phone  || 'No phone found';;

    }).fail(function() {
        alert("Error found. Please refresh your page.");
    });

    // Info window


    this.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({


    });


    // Marker

    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.long),
        map: map,
        title: data.name
    });


    this.marker.addListener('click', function() {

        self.contentString = '<div class="info-window-content"><div class="title"><b>' + data.name + "</b></div>" +
            '<div class="content"><a href="' + self.URL + '">' + self.URL + "</a></div>" +
            '<div class="content">' + self.street + "</div>" +
            '<div class="content">' + self.city + "</div>" +
            '<div class="content"><a href="tel:' + self.phone + '">' + self.phone + "</a></div></div>";

        self.infoWindow.setContent(self.contentString);

        self.infoWindow.open(map, this);

        self.marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.marker.setAnimation(null);
        }, 2100);
    });

    this.bounce = function(place) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(self.marker, 'click');
    };
};


//-ViewModel
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // create array of places

    this.locationList = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.searchLocation = ko.observable('');

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: {
            lat: 37.77986,
            lng: -122.429
        }
    });

    initialLocations.forEach(function(locationItem) {
        self.locationList.push(new Location(locationItem));
    });

    this.filteredList = ko.computed(function() {
        var filter = self.searchLocation().toLowerCase();
        if (!filter) {
            self.locationList().forEach(function(locationItem) {
                locationItem.visible(true);
            });
            return self.locationList();
        } else {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.locationList(), function(locationItem) {
                var string = locationItem.name.toLowerCase();
                var result = (string.search(filter) >= 0);
                locationItem.visible(result);
                return result;
            });
        }
    }, self);

    this.mapElem = document.getElementById('map');
    this.mapElem.style.height = window.innerHeight - 50;
}
// Bind the VeiewModel to the view using knockout
function startApp() {
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
}

function errorHandling() {
    alert("Error loading page, try refresh in page.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to create a global variable where to save the infoWindow that is being displayed:

   var infowindow = null;
2. Every time you go to show an infowindow you check if this is not null and you close it.

   if (infowindow) {
       infowindow.close();
   }
3. Then create a new instance and assign it to the variable:

   infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow ();
   ...

If you have questions, write me and I'll help you.

excuse my English

Here you can find more answers:
[Close all infowindows in Google Maps API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539905/close-all-infowindows-in-google-maps-api-v3)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I tried to do as you suggested and it didn't work. Can you help? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is better to avoid global variables.  You can create the infoWindow in the ViewModel and pass it to the Location objects.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could share the `infoWindow` with all your `Location` objects.  You need to move the `infoWindow` from `Location` to `AppViewModel` in order to have only an instance of this object.

Then, the `AppViewModel` should be:

```
//-ViewModel
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // create array of places

    this.locationList = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.searchLocation = ko.observable('');

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: {
            lat: 37.77986,
            lng: -122.429
        }
    });

    // ** Move the infoWindow from Location to AppViewModel.    
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    });


    initialLocations.forEach(function(locationItem) {
        // To each Location object, pass the same infoWindow object
        self.locationList.push(new Location(locationItem, infoWindow, map));
    });

    // from here, the same code you have in AppViewModel
    ...
}
```

Now Add a parameter to the `Location` function (object):

```
function Location(data, infoWindow, map) {
```

Comment the `infoWindow`(or delete it, because you have it as a parameter):

```
    //// Info window
    //this.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    //});
```

And the change the `click` listener:

```
    this.marker.addListener('click', function() {

        self.contentString = '<div class="info-window-content"><div class="title"><b>' + data.name + "</b></div>" +
            '<div class="content"><a href="' + self.URL + '">' + self.URL + "</a></div>" +
            '<div class="content">' + self.street + "</div>" +
            '<div class="content">' + self.city + "</div>" +
            '<div class="content"><a href="tel:' + self.phone + '">' + self.phone + "</a></div></div>";

        // ** Here, remove the 'self' in order to use the infoWindow received as parameter.
        infoWindow.setContent(self.contentString);

        // ** Here, remove the 'self' in order to use the infoWindow received as parameter.
        infoWindow.open(map, this);

        self.marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.marker.setAnimation(null);
        }, 2100);
    });
```

This way all your `Location` objects will see the same `infoWindow` object.  There is going to be only one `infoWindow`.

**Update**
As for comments, I see that `map` becomes a global variable.  It is declared in `AppViewModel()` but it should be declared with `var` or `let`.  I changed its definition.

Then, we should add a new parameter to the `Location` object, the map, because now is not a globlal variable.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly. However                                                       // ** Move the infoWindow from Location to AppViewModel.    
    self.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    }); need to be just infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    });

Comment: Then `infoWindow` becomes a global variable.  You need to declare it with `var` or `let`:  `var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ });`.  The `map` variable should be `var map`.

Comment: Please, have a look to this link:  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp.  "If you assign a value to a variable that has not been declared, it will automatically become a GLOBAL variable.".