# Google Maps API - How to close all open info windows when opening a new info window?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following function that opens my info window for the marker, I am struggling to understand how I can close the active / opened info window before opening another, so that only one info window is active at a time?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map_marker, 'click', function () {

    info_window.setContent(this.html)
    info_window.open(self.map, this)
    document.querySelector("#js-reset-zoom").classList.remove('active')

})

this.map_markers.push( map_marker )
```

Answer (score 0):

See the answer on this other question. 
[Close all infowindows in Google Maps API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539905/close-all-infowindows-in-google-maps-api-v3)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map_marker, 'click', function () {
if (info_window) {
    info_window.close();
}
info_window.setContent(this.html)
info_window.open(self.map, this)
document.querySelector("#js-reset-zoom").classList.remove('active')
```

})

this.map_markers.push( map_marker )

Comment: I don't know what the rest of your code looks like so you may want to restructure it like the other questions so you are only using one infoWindow so only one is open at a time.