# Google Maps and Their Markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a JSON array of Marker positions being pulled into a Google map - This works fine.

I also have infoWindows linked to each of those markers - These also work fine.

However, when I click a marker (in any browser), the infoWindow only appears over the last added marker.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/8WDwn/10/
and here is my loop:

```
for (var a = 0; a < dealer_markers.length; a++) {
    var tmpLat = dealer_markers[a].lat;
    var tmpLng = dealer_markers[a].lng;
    var tmpName = dealer_markers[a].name;
    var tmpAdr = dealer_markers[a].adr;
    var tmpTel = dealer_markers[a].pc;
    var tmpPc = dealer_markers[a].tel;

    contentString[a] = '<div id="bg"><h2 class="title">'+tmpName+'</h2><h3 class="address">'+tmpAdr+'</h3><h3 class="pc">'+tmpPc+'</h3><h3 class="telephone">'+tmpTel+'</h3></div>';
    var content = contentString[a];

    dealer[a] = new google.maps.LatLng(tmpLat,tmpLng);

    deal = dealer[a];

    marker[a] = new google.maps.Marker({ 
        map:map,
        position: deal,
        icon:'dealer.png',
        title: "|"+new google.maps.LatLng(dealer[a].Ja,dealer[a].Ka)
    });

    lat = marker[a].position.Ja;
    lng = marker[a].position.Ka;

    compositeLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    mark = marker[a];


    google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function(a) {
        if (mark.infowindow) {
            mark.infowindow.close();
        }

        mark.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
            content: contentString[marker.indexOf(this)]
        });

        mark.infowindow.open(map,mark);
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use closures. Let me check.

Comment: Please reduce the code in the jsfiddle example so we can pin the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, you can use a closure to work around the problem. Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/bhSmf/). I created a wrapper function that:

1. creates a marker
2. optionally attaches an onclick handler

Inside that handler:

1. it attaches a blank infoWindow to the map (if necessary)
2. it hides that window, changes its content and shows it again over the marker (logic borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966744/closing-any-open-info-windows-in-google-maps-api-v3))

---

```
function _newGoogleMapsMarker(param) {
    var r = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: param._map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(param._lat, param._lng),
        title: param._head
    });
    if (param._data) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(r, 'click', function() {
            // this -> the marker on which the onclick event is being attached
            if (!this.getMap()._infoWindow) {
                this.getMap()._infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            }
            this.getMap()._infoWindow.close();
            this.getMap()._infoWindow.setContent(param._data);
            this.getMap()._infoWindow.open(this.getMap(), this);
        });
    }
    return r;
}


for (var a = 0; a < dealer_markers.length; a++) {
    .
    .
    .
    var marker = _newGoogleMapsMarker({
        _map: map,
        _lat: tmpLat,
        _lng: tmpLng,
        _head: '|' + new google.maps.LatLng(tmpLat, tmpLng),
        _data: '...'
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are creating a function in a loop and then using **mark** inside that function so it will always appear next to the last marker created as **mark** is reassigned on each loop iteration

It is also good practice not to create functions in loops, so I would rewrite like this:

```
var map = null // your map created here

var infowindow = null;

var itemClick = function(a) {
    if (this.infowindow) {
        this.infowindow.close();
    }

    this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString[marker.indexOf(this)]
    });

    this.infowindow.open(this.map, a);

}

for (var a = 0; a < dealer_markers.length; a++) {

    ///  Other code.....

    google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', itemClick);
}
```

Comment: Im sorry but I dont have time to read through your code right now. My answer was based on the snippet you provided but after quick glance at your code I can see that it wont work because of the scope you are creating the markers in. I will try and have another look later (if the question doesn't get answered before)