# Google Maps API V3 - add event listener to all markers?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

There's got to be a way to add a listener to ALL MARKERS, currently I'm adding a listener to each one using a loop which feels really wrong...

This feels wrong:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(unique_marker_id, 'click', function(){
    //do something with this marker...                   
});
```

Answer (score 39):

In both `Marker` and `MarkerWithLabel` case, you might just as well use the ***this*** keyword to refer the object to which the event handler is attached:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
   // do something with this marker ...
   this.setTitle('I am clicked');
});
```

***this*** here is referring to the particular marker object.

Comment: I think using "this" is the right call, especially if you forget to declare the "marker" variable with "var" like I just did, thus making it global and spending an hour trying to figure out why every marker's click returns the same info...

Comment: +1 for more apropriate and easy way of resolving problem. I think this is the best answer.

Comment: This avoids polluting the global namespace with m1, m2, etc. Way more elegant!

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of having to add the listener to every marker individually...

Comment: It is not showing anything on marker click. *setTitle* with *this* is not working at all.

Comment: OMG I wish I could upvote you like 100 times. Awesome solution! Thanks so much!

Comment: this has not anything to do with the question

Comment: Why all the upvotes? He's still applying the event to every single marker.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot with another problem.

Answer (score 32):

You need to add the listener to each marker, but you can make it easy by e.g. defining a function like

```
function createMarker(pos, t) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({       
        position: pos, 
        map: m,  // google.maps.Map 
        title: t      
    }); 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
       alert("I am marker " + marker.title); 
    }); 
    return marker;  
}
```

and call it appropriately:

```
var m1 = createMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(...), "m1");
var m2 = createMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(...), "m2");
```

or in a loop, etc.

Comment: +1 This definitely helped me, and looping through this function is perfect.

Comment: Nice simple solution

Answer (score 8):

If you're using GoogleMaps v3.16 or later, you can add the event handler to the whole `map.data` layer.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), options);
map.data.loadGeoJson('http://yourserver.com/path/to/geojson.json');
map.data.addListener('click', function(e) {
    // this - instance of the layer object, in this case - map.data
    // e.feature - instance of the feature object that initiated the event
    // e.latLng - the position of the event
});
```

see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-event

Comment: This is gone in v3.34.x, and probably in some versions between then and now.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to do this using FusionTablesLayer. It's a bit of work setting everything up correctly, but once you're done, it's ultra-fast, even with thousands of markers.

You basically create a public table in Google Docs and query it from your webpage. The map is pre-generated on Googles' servers, which is why it performs so well.

A complete demo page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Google Maps Demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style type="text/css">
    html, body, #map_canvas
    {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() 
    {
      var denmark = new google.maps.LatLng(56.010666, 10.936890);

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        center: denmark,
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });

      layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: 'Coordinates',
          from: '1234567'
        }
      });
      layer.setMap(map);

      google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function (event) { 
        alert('Hello World!'); });

    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Check out this article for more info, ["Too Many Markers!"](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers) by Luke Mahe and Chris Broadfoot from the Google Geo APIs Team.

Comment: the link is broken now

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get an answer here:
[Google Maps and Their Markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055843/google-maps-and-their-markers)

and a demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/salman/bhSmf/

Answer (score 0):

This simplest way is this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
var marker = this;
alert("Tite for this marker is:" + this.title);
});
```

Comment: This function does not exist in the API.

Answer (score 0):

To Expand on Jiri answer purley for those searching who also wish to add a custom label etc.  In the spirit of Jiri post, in shorthand version:

```
    var m1 = createMarker({lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044}, "m1", "<div id=\"content\"><div id=\"siteNotice\"></div>  <h1 id=\"firstHeading\" class=\"firstHeading\">m1</h1> <div id=\"bodyContent\">Some info</div> </div>");

function createMarker(pos, t, d) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({       
        position: pos, 
        map: map, 
        title: t      
    }); 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click", function() { 
        alert("I am marker " + marker.title); 
    new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: d }).open(map, marker);

    }); 
    return marker;  
}
```

Remove alert, just there to show the action etc.  as with Jiri's info, you can add m2, m3 etc.  I thought this simply finished things off.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Note: I have a set of data, and it is named by the variable data.
 * The variable data is an array
 */

//Here I get the length of the data
var dataLength = data.length;

//Then I iterate through all my pieces of data here
//NOTICE THAT THE KEYWORD let IS SO IMPORTANT HERE
for(let markerIterator = 0; markerIterator < dataLength; markerIterator++) {
    /* This creates a new google maps marker based on my data's latitude and 
     * longitude
     */
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: data[markerIterator].latitude, lng: 
        data[markerIterator].longitude },
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        /* This will spit out the unique markerIterator value for each marker when 
         * clicked. It is a unique value because I defined markerIterator with the 
         * keyword let!
         */
        console.log(markerIterator); 

        // Use the keyword this to refer to each unique marker, for example:
        map.setCenter(this.getPosition());              
    });
}
```

Comment: ,Add description to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What i've Done is, when adding new `marker` on map and before pushing it into `markers = []` array, i just add listener to it `marker.addListener('click', () => { // Do Something here});`

Complete Code:

```
// Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.
    function addMarker(location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            icon: {
                url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png"
            },
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            map: map
        });
        marker.addListener("click",
            () => {
                console.log("Marker Click Event Fired!");
            });
        markers.push(marker);

    }
```

[LINK](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Google-Maps-API-V3-Add-click-event-listener-to-all-multiple-markers.aspx) i followed!

It was really hard for me to find a specific answer to my need. But this one is working now and everywhere for me!
Regards! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
var map;
function initialize_map(locations) {
  var options = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.933688,30.331879),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), options);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][lat], locations[i][lng]),
      map: map,
      title: locations[i][title]
    });
    set_event(marker);
    bounds.extend(marker.position);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
function set_event(marker) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    // do something with this marker ...
  });
}
```

Comment: This is still adding the listener to every marker individually

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
   function setMarkers(map, locations) {
      var image = ['circle_orange.png','circle_blue .png'];
      for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var stations = locations[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(stations[1], stations[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          icon: image[stations[3]],
          title: stations[0],
          zIndex: stations[3],
          optimized: false
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "No data available"
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        infowindow.setContent("We can include any station information, for example: Lat/Long: "+ stations[1]+" , "+stations[2]);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
      }
    }
```